# bootstrap submenu parent background goes black on hover of its submenu items

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I have a normal bootstrap dropdown implemented with submenus. When I hover on the dropdown elements such as "safdgs" and "lplplp" the background turns a little gray which is perfect

[image: When Hovering over "lplplp"]

But when I hover over the sub menu item called new folder, the "lplplp" menu item turns black. I do not want this to happen.

[image: When Hovering over "new folder"]

How can I fix this? Why does the parent go black when I hover hover over the submenu? Also, I have this dropdown connected to a black navbar (via the navbar-inverse class) so I want a solution that only targets this scenario mentioned above because the dropdown behaves properly when the screen is smaller...[image]

BASIC IDEA:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#">Dropdown Button</a>
                <ul  class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu" style="width:300px">
                        <li class="dropdown-submenu dropdown-submenu-bookmark">
                            <a tabindex="-1" href="" >
                                <i class="fa fa-folder-o fa-1x padding-right-10px"></i>
                                Parent Drop 1
                            </a>
                             <ul style="width: 300px" class="dropdown-menu bookmarkDrop">

                              <li><a tabindex="-1" href=""><i class="fa fa-file-image-o fa-1x padding-right-10px"></i>New Folder 1</a></li>
                              <li><a tabindex="-1" href=""><i class="fa fa-file-image-o fa-1x padding-right-10px"></i>New Folder 2</a></li>
                              <li><a tabindex="-1" href=""><i class="fa fa-file-image-o fa-1x padding-right-10px"></i>New Folder 3</a></li>

                            </ul>

                        </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you set up a fiddle ?

Comment: It's a little too complicated to set up a fiddle..but I've added some code to my original question with the basic set up

Comment: It's really hard to debug without at least the CSS to go with it. Is it somewhere live where we could take a look?

Comment: Hi, without any css to look over try doing this.  If you have any custom css place the Bootstrap css link below your custom css links as a quick way to see if any custom css is overriding bootstrap. And see if the problem no longer there.